# Fluent NHibernate: passing parameters to a user method

Tags: c#, methods, fluent-nhibernate, parameter-passing

I have a problem that is driving me crazy with MVC, C# and Fluent NHibernate (ASP.Net 4.5).

I have a call to FNH "GetSession().Query()...." which in turn calls a simple static method "VitCommon.ChooseLanguage" passing a parameter "language" by content. 
The weird thing is that "language" contains "ita" just before the call is made while at the moment ChooseLanguage is entered it has misteriously been changed to another value.

Looking at the call stack I can see that nothing has been called except a bunch of FNH methods and ChooseLanguage.

I already tried these:

1. used a local variable in the method:      var _language = language;
2. used a local variable with String.Copy(): var _language = String.Copy(language);
3. made ChooseLanguage not static
4. a switch statement that sets _language with literal constants

Nothing of these worked. These are the piece of code involved.

```
public List<Allegato> GetAllegatiBySchedaPk(Vit.TipoScheda tipoScheda, int pkScheda, string tipoMediaSupportati = "", string language = "ita")
{
    tipoMediaSupportati = tipoMediaSupportati + "";
    var arTipoMediaSupportati = tipoMediaSupportati.Split(new string[] { "||" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var listTassonoimieImmagini = arTipoMediaSupportati.Select(s => new TassonomiaMultimedia {
        ID = Convert.ToInt32(s.Split(';')[0]),
        Descrizione = s.Split(';')[1]
    }).ToList();
    var val = GetSession().Query<TabcMultimedia>()
   .Join(GetSession().Query<Immagini>(), l => l.fk_immagine, r => r.pk_immagine, (l, r) => new { Multimedia = l, Immagini = r })
   .Where(w => w.Multimedia.fk_schedatipo == (int)tipoScheda && w.Multimedia.fk_chiavescheda == pkScheda && w.Immagini.fk_tipo_immagini == 4)
   .OrderBy(o => o.Multimedia.ordine)
   .Select(s => new Allegato {
       IdAllegato = s.Immagini.pk_immagine,
       Titolo = s.Multimedia.denom_ita != null ? VitCommon.ChooseLanguage(s.Multimedia, "denom", language) : VitCommon.ChooseLanguage(s.Immagini, "titolo", language),
       Didascalia = s.Multimedia.didasca_ita != null ? VitCommon.ChooseLanguage(s.Multimedia, "didasca", language) : VitCommon.ChooseLanguage(s.Immagini, "descrizione", language),
       Tassonomia = GetTassonomiaMultimedia(s.Multimedia.est_inv, listTassonoimieImmagini),
       Tipo = s.Immagini.immagine_tipo
   })
   .ToList();
    return val;
}


public static string ChooseLanguage(object oggettoCorrente, string FieldName, string LinguaVitCorrente, bool underscorePresent) {
  var underscore = "_";
  if (!underscorePresent) {
    underscore = "";
  }
  var retString = "";
  var processLang = LinguaVitCorrente;
  var lingue = LingueVit.GetLingue().Where(l => l.Suffisso.Equals(processLang)).SingleOrDefault();
  var i = 0;
  while (retString == "") {
    try {
      retString =
        (oggettoCorrente.GetType().GetProperty(FieldName + underscore + processLang).GetValue(oggettoCorrente, null) + "");
    }
    catch {
      retString = "Proprietà non trovata ('" + FieldName + underscore + processLang +
                  "')! il nome della proprietà è case sensitive e per ciascuna tipologia di campo deve essere unfirome, controllare nel mapping dell'oggetto.";
    }
    if (retString == "") {
      try {
        processLang = lingue.Alternative[i].Suffisso;
      }
      catch {
        retString = "not found";
      }
      i++;
    }
  }
  var returnVal = retString == "not found" ? "" : retString;
  return returnVal;
}
```

By trial and error have found that this way works:

```
var listaAllegati = GetSession().Query<TabcMultimedia>()
    .Join(GetSession().Query<Immagini>(), l => l.fk_immagine, r => r.pk_immagine, (l, r) => new { Multimedia = l, Immagini = r })
    .Where(w => w.Multimedia.fk_schedatipo == (int)tipoScheda && w.Multimedia.fk_chiavescheda == pkScheda && w.Immagini.fk_tipo_immagini == 4)
    .OrderBy(o => o.Multimedia.ordine)
    .ToList();

var listaAllegatiLingua = listaAllegati.Select(s => new Allegato {
    IdAllegato = s.Immagini.pk_immagine,
    Titolo = s.Multimedia.denom_ita != null ? VitCommon.ChooseLanguage(s.Multimedia, "denom", language) : VitCommon.ChooseLanguage(s.Immagini, "titolo", language),
    Didascalia = s.Multimedia.didasca_ita != null ? VitCommon.ChooseLanguage(s.Multimedia, "didasca", language) : VitCommon.ChooseLanguage(s.Immagini, "descrizione", language),
    Tassonomia = GetTassonomiaMultimedia(s.Multimedia.est_inv, listTassonoimieImmagini),
    Tipo = s.Immagini.immagine_tipo
})
.ToList();

return listaAllegatiLingua;
```

Even putting var _language = "ita" works, of course it makes the whole method useless.

Seems that some multi-threading in FNH is the culprit but it is hard for me to imagine what and how, may someone give me help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first Select takes an expression which is parsed and partially converted to sql which may explain the lost value. Use AsEnumerable to delay the creation of the results to the code but dont have an intermediate list.

```
return GetSession().Query<TabcMultimedia>()
    .Join(GetSession().Query<Immagini>(), l => l.fk_immagine, r => r.pk_immagine, (l, r) => new { Multimedia = l, Immagini = r })
    .Where(w => w.Multimedia.fk_schedatipo == (int)tipoScheda && w.Multimedia.fk_chiavescheda == pkScheda && w.Immagini.fk_tipo_immagini == 4)
    .OrderBy(o => o.Multimedia.ordine)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(s => new Allegato {
        IdAllegato = s.Immagini.pk_immagine,
        Titolo = s.Multimedia.denom_ita != null ? VitCommon.ChooseLanguage(s.Multimedia, "denom", language) : VitCommon.ChooseLanguage(s.Immagini, "titolo", language),
        Didascalia = s.Multimedia.didasca_ita != null ? VitCommon.ChooseLanguage(s.Multimedia, "didasca", language) : VitCommon.ChooseLanguage(s.Immagini, "descrizione", language),
        Tassonomia = GetTassonomiaMultimedia(s.Multimedia.est_inv, listTassonoimieImmagini),
        Tipo = s.Immagini.immagine_tipo
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you Firo, it turned out to be the best solution as it not only fixed the issue (it "freezes" the generated sql, so the subsequent processing no more messes the parameter) but also gets better overall performance. 

Please note that the position where the .AsEnumerable clause is put is sensitive for the result.

Thank you very much again.